# Dagger2 Cannot provided without a @Inject constructor

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

**//MODULES**

```
@Module
public class PresenterModule {

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public MainPresenter provideMainPresenter() {
        return new MainPresenter();
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public PreLoginPresenter providePreLoginPresenter() {
        return new PreLoginPresenter();
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public NotificationPresenter provideNotificationPresenter() {
        return new NotificationPresenter();
    }
}

@Module
public class UserLoginModule {

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public UserModel getUser(){
        return new UserModel();
    }
}
```

**//COMPONENTS**

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = {UserLoginModule.class})
public interface UserLoginComponent {

    void injectSharedPreferences(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences);
    void injectPreLoginPresenter(PreLoginActivity preLoginActivity);
}

@PerActivity
@Component(modules = {PresenterModule.class})
public interface PresenterComponent {

    //void injectMainPresenter(MainActivity mainActivity);
    void injectPreLoginPresenter(PreLoginActivity preLoginActivity);
    //void injectNotificationPresenter(NotificationActivity notificationActivity);

}
```

`
**//PRELOGINPRESENTER**

```
public class PreLoginPresenter {

@Inject
UserModel userModel;

public String onStateSelected(String state) {
        userModel.setState(state);
        return userModel.getState();
 }

 }
```

**//PRELOGINACTIVITY`**

**//INSIDE THE ONCREATE**

```
//Instantiate dagger 2
                 PresenterComponent presenterComponent =                        DaggerPresenterComponent.builder()
                .build();
              presenterComponent.injectPreLoginPresenter(PreLoginActivity.this);//passar o contexto para o componente

    //Instantiate dagger 2
        UserLoginComponent userLoginComponent = DaggerUserLoginComponent.builder()
            .build();
        userLoginComponent.injectPreLoginPresenter(PreLoginActivity.this);//passar o contexto para o componente``
```

**//ERROR LOG**

> Error:(18, 53) error: cannot find symbol class
>   DaggerPresenterComponent Error:(19, 53) error: cannot find symbol
>   class DaggerUserLoginComponent Error:(19, 10) error:
>   gorick.gradesprojectandroid.MVP.Presenter.Presenters.PreLoginPresenter
>   cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an
>   @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method. This type supports members
>   injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
>   gorick.gradesprojectandroid.MVP.Presenter.Presenters.PreLoginPresenter
>   is injected at
>   gorick.gradesprojectandroid.MVP.View.PreLoginActivity.preLoginPresenter
>   gorick.gradesprojectandroid.MVP.View.PreLoginActivity is injected at
>   gorick.gradesprojectandroid.Dagger2.Component.UserLoginComponent.injectPreLoginPresenter(preLoginActivity)

Answer (score 2):

You've bound your PreLoginPresenter in your PresenterModule, but you haven't installed it in your UserLoginComponent. This means that your UserLoginComponent doesn't have the bindings it needs to inject PreLoginPresenter into PreLoginActivity, so the code generation fails and it gives you that error message.

You shouldn't ever need to inject the same class with two different Components; there's no way to express that one component satisfies certain bindings and another component satisfies others. Instead, make sure you have one component that covers everything, and inject using that.

Comment: I did this, and now is giving me a NullPointerException, i discovered is because @Inject UserModel userModel is not injecting nothing. What should i do?

Comment: Can i instantiate the dagger2 component in a class that is not an activity? like at PreLoginPresenter? i need the object there

Comment: You can create a Dagger2 component wherever you'd like, but if you're using a library or framework (that provides `@PerActivity`) you should follow that framework's expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still doesn't work cuz is not injecting the object. but thanks for try. Dude i'm for weeks trying to learn dagger2 and still not success. Just dont have any simple tutorial or clean article to learn this. Almost everything full of gaps of information and this is almost driving me crazy. rsrs maybe one day i'll understand.